# Compare all elements between arrays and return all possible matches

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to create a function that compares all elements of an array with all elements of a second array and will return all possible matches, and message if no matches are found. When I try to implement the code, I get an index out of bound error. The inner for loop probably maxed out before the outer for loop can finish running. How do I modify it to prevent such a scenario from occurring?

```java
Stocks[] stockList3 = new Stocks[3];
stockList3[0] = new Stocks("a", 2, 1, "Buy");
stockList3[1] = new Stocks("a", 3, 1, "Buy");
stockList3[2] = new Stocks("a", 4, 1, "Buy");

Stocks[] stockList4 = new Stocks[3];
stockList4[0] = new Stocks("a", 2, 1, "Buy");
stockList4[1] = new Stocks("a", 5, 1, "Buy");
stockList4[2] = new Stocks("a", 4, 1, "Buy");

public void matching(Stocks[] array1, Stocks[] array2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < array2.length; j++) {
            if (array1[i].stockPrice == array2[j].stockPrice) {
                System.out.println("It's a match at $" + array1[i].stockPrice);
            }
            System.out.println("still searching...");
        }
        System.out.println("first loop test...");
    }
}
```

Comment: the second for loop : `int j=0; i<array2.length;j++`. Use `j` instead of `i`

Comment: Okay, thank you for spotting that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about instead of two `for loops`, use `Set` collection to store existed `stockPrices` for one of an array?

```
public static List<Stocks> matching(Stocks[] one, Stocks[] two) {
    Set<Integer> stockPrices = Arrays.stream(one)
                                     .map(stock -> stock.stockPrice)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return Arrays.stream(two)
                 .filter(stock -> stockPrices.contains(stock.stockPrice))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It use **O(n)** additional memory (where **n** is **one.length**) with **O(n + m)** performance time (where **m** is **two.length**).

Answer (score 0):

In your j-loop you were saying `i<array2.length` instead of `j<array2.length`

```
public void matching ( Stocks[] array1, Stocks[] array2){
    for (int i=0; i<array1.length;i++){

        for (int j=0;
                 j<array2.length;  //this j was an i
                 j++){

            if (array1[i].stockPrice == array2[j].stockPrice){
                System.out.println("It's a match at $" + array1[i].stockPrice);



            }
            System.out.println("still searching...");
        }
        System.out.println("first loop test...");   
    }

}
```